# It does not return the expected output

Tags: linux, bash

The intention of my script is to print the users who have inactive days of more than 30. This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

max=30
grep -E ^[^:]+:[^\!*] /etc/shadow | awk -F: '{print $1" "$7}' | while read user days
do 
    if [ $days -gt $max ]
    then
        echo $user
        echo $days
    fi
done
```

I created 2 users, test and test2 each with 30 days and 50 days inactivity respectively. This script returns me both when I only need to print test2 with 50 days of inactivity.

Comment: Unquoted `>` is redirection operator. You must use `-gt` between `[` and `]`.

Comment: I tried to that however it tells me -gt: unary operator expected

Comment: `-gt` is the correct operator. If you got an error, you should post a question that reproduces *that* error.

Comment: Run your code through http://shellcheck.net before editing your question, though.

Comment: `unary operator expected` implies one of your variables is empty and since you've removed the double quotes what you get is `[ -gt 30 ]`; add the double quotes and you get `[ '' -gt 30 ]` which should generate a message `integer expression expected`

Comment: Yeap I have done so and it gave me the integer expression expected

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making this more complicated than needed.

Since you already have `awk` in your pipe, that can replace `grep` and compare to `max`.

Simple example.

Given:

```
cat file
dawg 2 3 4 5 6 45
boosh 2 3 4 5 6 25
```

You can do:

```
max=30
awk -v max="$max" '$7>max{print $1, $7}' shadow
dawg 2 3 4 5 6 45
```

I left out the `grep` portion but you can either keep that as a pipe (if it is working) or integrate into the awk.

---

If you *want* to compare two integers in Bash, you either need to use the correct test, which is `(( arithmetic context ))`

```
$ (( 1>2 )); echo $?  
1
$ (( 10>2 )); echo $? 
0
# 0 means TRUE
```

or the correct operator which is `[ -gt ]`:

```
$ [ 10 -gt 2 ]; echo $? 
0
$ [ 1 -gt 2 ]; echo $?  
1
```

But if you use `>` inside of `[[ .. ]]` you are actually comparing strings and may be the wrong answer:

```
$ [[ 10 < 2 ]]; echo $?  
0                      # '0' means 'true' 10 < 2 only as strings
```

And you must use double `[[ .. ]]` to use `>` otherwise it is the redirection operator. (Thanks M. Nejat Aydin
...)

Comment: `But if you use > inside of [ .. ] you are actually comparing strings`: No. Unquoted `>` is redirection operator inside `[...]`. It doesn't compare anything.

Comment: Drak! You are right. Edit made. I have use `[[ ... ]]` for so long I forgot that...